# Having Sphinx issues with Sharetribe (Heroku + FlyingSphinx)

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx, sharetribe

I've managed to mostly successfully get ShareTribe up and running on a heroku account.

Following this great guide here: https://gist.github.com/svallory/d08e9baa88e18d691605

When I got to actually playing with custom fields and searching I realized that the sphinx indexing wasn't running, a bit of digging later .. seems that `flying-sphix index` isn't the way to go .. you're meant to use `rake ts:index` and `rake ts:rebuild` to initially do it .. (maybe) ..

In any case .. I'm at the point where this whole sphinx side of it seems a bit magical and messy and I'm sure its something very dumb I'm missing.

1. Is there something I need to run to initialize (or re-initialize) sphinx so it does its thing
2. What's the correct thing to run every hour to re-index like the guide suggests
3. Are these steps in that gist sufficient? Are they missing some major step?

Oh yea the main symptom is that on the UI side I keep seeing "Search is currently unavailable. Try searching again soon." and in the logs it basically says the index is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Well this turned out to be a bit silly and the internet is full of conflicting errors .. finally found a relevant error messgae in FlyingSphinx logs ..

When setting things up, you may need to configure the SSL cert chian, sharetribe seems to have the RDS cert chain in there by default, so if using cleardb .. you need to switch that back out.

This finally shed some light on it:
http://support.flying-sphinx.com/discussions/problems/1882-ssl-connection-error

Also the correct commands here are:

- `flying-sphinx rebuild` initially
- `flying-sphinx index` thereafter